# how to generate a random number without math.random() in typescript

Tags: node.js

math.random() function is not safe here is the error showing in sonarqube so need to replace it

Need to change the math.random() ,it should accept by the sonarqube

Comment: What is Sonarqube saying? What are you using `Math.random()` for in your application?

Comment: you could try writing a custom function for generating random numbers

Comment: @SanuKhan Let say that I want to write a custom function doing exactly what Math.random() does, because I'm just not using it for any security nor infra, I just want to play around with some data, so why sonar should not allow me to use this existing method when I need it and I know exactly what I'm doing ?
Maybe I should just turn off this sonar security hotspot because it is just a BIG false positive, in my case at least.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [Crypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto) interface to generate a UUID or the [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package? Both will generate a random UUID.

If Crypto is available you can use the method `getRandomValues`.

```
const array = new Uint32Array(10);
self.crypto.getRandomValues(array);

console.log("Your lucky numbers:");
for (const num of array) {
  console.log(num);
}
```

Which outputs

```
Your lucky numbers:
1673188906
2644299508
3801613084
1704201466
4276632534
1776440239
2227034128
3687628501
749833900
4154055822
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the current timestamp to generate a random number

`Math.floor(Date.now() /1000);`

Math library is optional here

`Date.now() /1000;`